# Getting all calendars events on Android 4.0+ for the current day

Tags: android, calendar, google-calendar-api, android-4.2-jelly-bean

It's been quite some time that have been looking for an answer to my issue. 
What I want to do : get all events from all calendars for the current day

I'm able to do that without any issue on pre-ICS devices (2.2 to 3.2 Android versions). On Android 4.0+, since the introduction of the new calendar API's, I've been dealing with it with quite success. Well, that's what I thought before testing on others devices than mine. Sometimes my code work, sometimes it won't. Repeating events doesn't appear on some devices or on other devices, all events are displayed (not only the one for the curent day).

I think that the issue is from one line of code but I can't find how to do it correctly :

```
    cursor = contentResolver.query(CalendarContract.Events.CONTENT_URI, COLS, "("+CalendarContract.Events.DTSTART+">"+now+" and "+CalendarContract.Events.DTEND+"<"+endOfDay.getTimeInMillis()+") or (("+CalendarContract.Events.ALL_DAY+"=1) and "+"("+CalendarContract.Events.DTSTART+">="+timeAllDay.getTimeInMillis()+") and "+"("+CalendarContract.Events.DTEND+"<="+endTimeAllDay.getTimeInMillis()+"))", null, null);
```

Here is all the class that I created with the above line :

```
    public class ICSCalendar extends AsyncTask<Intent, String, Intent> 
    {
      private static final String[] COLS = new String[] {CalendarContract.Events.TITLE, CalendarContract.Events.DTSTART, CalendarContract.Events.DTEND, CalendarContract.Events.ALL_DAY};

@Override
protected Intent doInBackground(Intent... params) 
{
    ContentResolver contentResolver = Alert.mContext.getContentResolver();
    Cursor cursor = null;

    try
    {
        long now = new Date().getTime();
        Calendar endOfDay = Calendar.getInstance();
        endOfDay.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, 23);
        endOfDay.set(Calendar.MINUTE, 59);
        endOfDay.set(Calendar.SECOND, 59);

        Calendar timeAllDay = Calendar.getInstance();
        timeAllDay.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, 0);
        timeAllDay.set(Calendar.MINUTE, 0);
        timeAllDay.set(Calendar.SECOND, 0);

        Calendar endTimeAllDay = Calendar.getInstance();
        endTimeAllDay.add(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, 1);
        endTimeAllDay.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, 2);
        endTimeAllDay.set(Calendar.MINUTE, 0);
        endTimeAllDay.set(Calendar.SECOND, 1);

        cursor = contentResolver.query(CalendarContract.Events.CONTENT_URI, COLS, "("+CalendarContract.Events.DTSTART+">"+now+" and "+CalendarContract.Events.DTEND+"<"+endOfDay.getTimeInMillis()+") or (("+CalendarContract.Events.ALL_DAY+"=1) and "+"("+CalendarContract.Events.DTSTART+">="+timeAllDay.getTimeInMillis()+") and "+"("+CalendarContract.Events.DTEND+"<="+endTimeAllDay.getTimeInMillis()+"))", null, null);

        Intent calendarData = new Intent(Alerts.CALENDAR_UI_DATA);
        int nb_events = 0;

        while(cursor.moveToNext()) 
        {
            nb_events++;

            final String title = cursor.getString(0);
            final Date begin = new Date(cursor.getLong(1));
            final Boolean allDay = !cursor.getString(3).equals("0");

            calendarData.putExtra("event_"+nb_events, (String) title);
            calendarData.putExtra("all_day_event_"+nb_events, (Boolean) allDay);

            Calendar beginEvent = Calendar.getInstance();   
            beginEvent.setTimeInMillis(cursor.getLong(1));
            String format = Alerts.get24HourMode(Alert.mContext) ? "kk:mm": "h:mm";
            CharSequence newTime = DateFormat.format(format, beginEvent);
            if(format == "h:mm")
            {
                if((beginEvent.get(Calendar.AM_PM) == 0))
                {
                    newTime = newTime + " A.M";
                }
                else
                {
                    newTime = newTime + " P.M";
                }
            }

            if(!allDay)
            {
                calendarData.putExtra("date_event_"+nb_events, newTime);
            }
            else
            {
                calendarData.putExtra("date_event_"+nb_events, Alert.mContext.getString(R.string.tts_whole_day_calendar_event));
            }
        }

        calendarData.putExtra("nb_events", nb_events);

        return calendarData;
    }
    catch(Exception e)
    {
        Log.d("DEBUG", ""+e);
        return null;
    }
}

@Override
protected void onPostExecute(Intent result) 
{
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onPostExecute(result);

    try
    {
        Alert.mContext.sendBroadcast(result);
    }
    catch(NullPointerException e){}
}

@Override
protected void onPreExecute() 
{
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onPreExecute();
}

@Override
protected void onProgressUpdate(String... values) 
{
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onProgressUpdate(values);
}
```

}

Anyone has an idea of how to get all events from all calendars for the current day for Android 4.0+ ?
Thanks all for your help :)

Answer (score 2):

In order to get recurring events you need the instances table, see more details [here](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/providers/calendar-provider.html#instances)

It's not as easy as it seems I'm afraid